# Angular 4 code coverage for HTTP response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I'm implementing Code coverage tasks for angular app. I have a `signUp()` in component.ts file. 
This is in spec.ts file.

```
class AppService extends ApiService {
    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http:HttpClient){
    super(http);
    }
    signUp(url):Observable<any>{
    if(url == 'examplesignup'){
      return Observable.of(
        {"account":[{
            username:"nandini", password:"abc"
          }]
       })}
       else {
            return Observable.throw({
              status: 404, statusText:'resource not found'
            })
      }   
    }
    }
```

and

```
  fit('should register new user', fakeAsync(() => {
  let result:any;
  appService.signUp('examplesignup')
    .subscribe( res => {
      result = res;
      expect(result.account[0].username).toBe("nandini");
    })
  }))
```

Even though I am putting the correct API the test case covers "error function" and doesn't cover the success part of the code. What is the mistake?

Please help and THANK YOU :)

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @i3lai3la There is no error.. the test case doesn't cover the success part of the api and only covers the error part.